# Build HikariCP from source

Tags: maven, hikaricp

I want to replace *BoneCP* with *HikariPC*. Downloaded `tar.gz` from [here](http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) and extracted. I don't know if this is a right command but inside `hikaricp-java6` directory I run

`$ mvn clean compile assembly:single`

maven prints error

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/gkiko/Downloads/brettwooldridge-HikariCP-5cb1000/hikaricp-java6/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/util/ConcurrentBag.java:[358,20] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method hasQueuedPredecessors()
location: class com.zaxxer.hikari.util.ConcurrentBag.Synchronizer
[ERROR] /Users/gkiko/Downloads/brettwooldridge-HikariCP-5cb1000/hikaricp-java6/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java:[150,37] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(boolean)
location: class java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
[ERROR] /Users/gkiko/Downloads/brettwooldridge-HikariCP-5cb1000/hikaricp-java6/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/HikariPool.java:[486,28] cannot find symbol
symbol  : method abort(java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService)
location: interface com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.IHikariConnectionProxy
[INFO] 3 errors 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T21:37:52+04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.1/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_65, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

Could you please tell me how to get `jar` file of *HikariCP* so I can add it to my java web app and use it with *sqlite*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java 8 is required to build HikariCP -- even the Java 6/7 compatible version.  But you can download the JAR from the maven central repository here:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chikaricp

Click on the 'jar' link for the HikariCP-java6 version 2.0.1 entry (second line).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you help me one more time? I have runtime exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig` on line `HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();`

Comment: I don't know what environment you're developing in, IDE or whatever, but this is a simple classpath issue where the HikariCP jar is not in the classpath at runtime.  Clearly it was in the path at compile time or you wouldn't have gotten this far.

Comment: I am also using HikariCP and it's working really well, thank you. Can you briefly explain what advantages/features are you using from Java 8? I am really curious about that Java 8 orientation.

Comment: Mostly it is "syntatic sugar" that we can't use in the Java 6 compatible jar, such as the new stream/filter API, lamba expressions, and even just Java 7 features like try-with-resources.  We also can use AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer.hasQueuedPredecessors() without penalty to provide a fairer pool.