# HikariCP LoggerFactory class definition not found

Tags: java, hikaricp

I've downloaded the HikariCP JAR from http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Chikaricp (the fifth row) and placed it in my build path. If you call

```
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
```

You get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.<clinit>(HikariConfig.java:45)
    at com.josevemon.microserver.App.<init>(App.java:41)
    at com.josevemon.microserver.App.main(App.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

According to a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25114022/555690,

> I don't know what environment you're developing in, IDE or whatever,
>   but this is a simple classpath issue where the HikariCP jar is not in
>   the classpath at runtime. Clearly it was in the path at compile time
>   or you wouldn't have gotten this far.

So HikariCP was in my path at compile time, but not on runtime. Well then, how do I have it at runtime? I'm using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: HikariCP uses Slf4j as logging-API, you can download it [here](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.6/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar) and add it to the classpath.

Comment: @vanOekel, thank you, but now it says that it couldn't load `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`!

Comment: You'll also need at least the slf4j "simple" logger implementation.  Poke around on their downloads to find it.  The "API" library just contains interface definitions, not actual logging implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include the following slf4j jars in the classpath:

- slf4j-jdk14-1.7.10.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar

I use maven so by adding the slf4j-jdk14-1.7.10.jar to my pom file it automatically adds the slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar. In your case you can download the jar files from here:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.10/
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/

Comment: I am in Netbeans IDE and it still not working after downloading the jar files and setting the classpath